# Deformation of a plate with a curved profile

Tags: modifiers

I have a plane with small thickness, I fold this plate in three steps.

step 1: folding the middle of the plate.

step 2: folding of the two dimensions of the plate.

step 3: wrap the two ends of the plate.

The following figures show these steps in detail.
I tried to modify it (Bend simple, curve, ...) without succeeding in getting only step one !!
My question, is there a way or how to trace these steps from a plate to get the final shape. I want these steps to be mobile and I want to save each deformation separately.

[image]

---

I created 7 keys to model my profile, so when I add keyframes for each key shape. I get a weird shape, maybe I have a problem using the Shapekeys !!!
In your tutorial, you added an extrusion but when you see our figure (step1), the profile has a thickness, how to add a thickness for the profile?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you use shape keys?

Comment: I just tried it since I never use.

Comment: Just use a single curve, give it some extrusion, bend as you need and use shapekeys for the curve.

Comment: When I want to use the melimeter unit (ex: 20mm), I find a problem of bending (deformed) a curve, can I ask to do step one, since I never work with the shapkeys.

Comment: When I use the video of this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO0riqHnhPU, I get a problem since the deformation in the middle does not work with the addition of Bend + shapekeys:

Comment: susu, I tried the 3 images of your help but you delete it !!!

Comment: Nate_Sycro27, I tried with the link above, but with my case it does not work. since the bending is in the middle of the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Add a curve.

[image]

Give it the extrusion you need (In the properties edtitor: Geometry>Extrude)

[image]

Give the curve a flat shape.

Add as many subdivisions to the curve as you will need for the final shape. Adding new subdivisions later complicates things.

[image]

Exit edit mode. Add a shape key (use the + sign on the right). That will be the basis shape.

[image]

Create another shape key it will be called Key 1

[image]

Enter edit mode again and move the control points to where you need.

[image]

Exit edit mode. Don't worry if your shape go back to the basic shape. The deformation has been recorded. Just set the value for Key 1 to 1.00

Make a new Shape Key, but this time click on the little triangle on the right and add "New Shape from mix" (Key 2)

[image]

[image]

Enter edit mode again and keep reshaping the curve and adding shape keys.

[image]

When you exit edit mode change the value of Key 1 to 0 and bring up the value to Key 2 to 1 before making the next key shape.

Keep making key shapes and deformations until you get to where you want.

To view all of the different shapes just bring up the value for individual keyshapes. To make an animation from this, add keyframes for the key shape key values.

[image]

Comment: I tried these steps, finally I found a problem with the curve especially when I increase the subdivision, see file attach(https://pasteall.org/blend/7430d2a613474ed7950cf4bfc41df924), How to animate these steps from the flat form to the final form to obtain for example 7 or 8 intermediate forms.

Comment: I don't follow links. Will not downlad files. Please edit your question with further developments. Did you change the subdivision after creating key shapes

Comment: Yes, i create curve with 4 parts, and I add subdivision = 5

Comment: Read the answer again. *Adding new subdivisions later complicates things*. New control points are not recalculated or averaged for previous shape keys. You will have to edit them manually. What you want to do is quite simple. Start over with the correct number of control points for the curve.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to redo the curve and see the tests, thanks for the help.

Comment: It's good for modeling of this mesh but when I add the animation between Shapekeys and Timekey, I found a difeculty when the curve change her form. can you see of your mesh if it's anim with a good or no!!